# Regex URL parsing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to phrase a line using regex but I've no idea how regex works.

This is the pattern I'm using now,

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+).*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$
```

A sample line I would pharse using the pattern.

```
124.99.152.202 - naveen [22/Nov/2013:10:41:17 +1300] "GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,888888888888888/FOLDER-NUMBER/i-dont-need-this-folder/nope/12.txt HTTP/1.1" "200" "8" "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
```

Now the problem is I need to get one more bit of info from above sample line.

"GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,888888888888888/**FOLDER-NUMBER**/12.txt HTTP/1.1"

How do I get this **FOLDER-NUMBER** integer value?

I tried this but I do not know how to filter it out, [Regex Fiddle](http://www.rexfiddle.net/cNzRk4O)

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+)/**FOLDER-NUMBER**/.*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$
```

Comment: This looks like a web server log.  Microsoft makes a GREAT product called LogParser that lets you run all kinds of parsing schemes over log files.

Comment: Yes this is a linux server log. Thanks but I will be parsing using PHP. :)

Comment: is the folder number you want always the same number of folders deep? `/p/XXXX/what_you_want`? or is it sometimes different (in which case, you're going to find this a lot more challenging)?

Comment: Yes, it will be always there but the integer value is not the same /p/XXX,XXX,XXX/I-WILL-BE-ALWAYS-HERE/these-stuff-vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, assuming you're always looking for the same number of folders deep, you could use:

`\].*?\/.*?\/.*?\/(.*?)\/`

The first matched group out of this will be the folder number you want, in the example provided.

See a working example: http://regex101.com/r/bO0aI1

To retrieve this via php, use:

```
preg_match(/\].*?\/.*?\/.*?\/(.*?)\//g, $yourLogLine, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //the first matched group
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I synced your code with the one I have, works perfectly. Thanks. :)